# Trying to write a foreach argument for a drupal7 cck field

Tags: jquery, drupal-7, cycle

I am using Drupal 7 and the jQuery and the Cycle2 feature. I followed the example code on this page.
http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/demo/basic.php
The code looks like this:

```
<div class="cycle-slideshow">
<img src="http://malsup.github.io/images/p1.jpg">
<img src="http://malsup.github.io/images/p2.jpg">
<img src="http://malsup.github.io/images/p3.jpg">
<img src="http://malsup.github.io/images/p4.jpg">
```

I created a Drupal cck multiple photo upload field called 'field_slider_photo'. And in my node template I wrote this.

```
<div class="cycle-slideshow">
<?php print render($content['field_slider_photo']); ?>
</div>
```

But this will display all photos all at once. I want them to play in the slideshow one at a time. Do I need to use an array or a foreach argument ?
I want to end up with something like this as an example:

```
<div class="cycle-slideshow">
<?php print render($content['field_slider_photo']); ?>Array1
<?php print render($content['field_slider_photo']); ?>Array2
<?php print render($content['field_slider_photo']); ?>Array3
</div>
```

I got it working but is there a better way to write this?

```
<div class="cycle-slideshow">
<?php print render($content['field_slider_photo'][0]); ?>
<?php print render($content['field_slider_photo'][1]); ?>
<?php print render($content['field_slider_photo'][2]); ?>
<?php print render($content['field_slider_photo'][3]); ?>
</div>
```

Comment: You need to output your html as expected for the javascript plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're close, give this a whirl.

```
<div class="cycle-slideshow">
  <?php foreach($content['field_slider_photo']['#items'] as $img): ?>
    <img src="<?php print file_create_url($img['uri']);?>">
  <?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: That works. Thank you very much!!! I may need help again to add the img alt tag in the foreach loop

Comment: Install the devel module. Then you can use the `dpm()` function to push variable info to the client. This will help you navigate the drupal object structure.

Comment: How do you use dpm() Do you insert this code in the page template:
    <pre><?php print dpm($variable); ?></pre>